# Move UIViewController from one presentingViewController to another without animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit

Im trying to move one view controller to another without animation:

```
viewController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
// viewController.presentingViewController != nil here
tabBarController.present(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

When i run this code i have a crash: `Application tried to present modally an active controller`

Answer (score 1):

You can put the present part in the completion handler of the dismiss call

```
viewController.dismiss(animated: false) {
    tabBarController.present(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: But i can see a frame between dismissing and presenting when there is no viewController

Comment: Im trying to present a viewController and switch its presenters in background

Comment: Hmmm, ok. Why want you do that in the first place? Maybe there's a different approach.

Comment: After signup in need to display profile "edit profile" page modally with animation. And right after animation i need replace signup page with profile page. So when editing is done "edit profile" closes with the modal animation and behind it should be his profile page